# Choppy jquery smooth scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all thanks for taking your time. To keep it short I will get right to the point.

Im using a jQuery smooth scroll script that has been working fine but right now im having a problem with the script. I don't know what I did wrong but it's really choppy when scrolling on Google Chrome. On Internet explorer and Firefox it's working fine. The images are ~2MB and the video is 3MB. Ive even tried to remove the video and images to see if it made any difference but there was none.

Ive cleared my google chrome cashe and cookies but still choppy. Also tested on

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

You can check my site live [here](http://mustafapiynirci.github.io)

Again, thanks for your time. Tips are always welcome.

PS: Im still working on changing the colors etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive been removing code to locate the problem and ive found that the wow.js script was the problem. Like Korgrue said, other actions are interfering with the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Beleive it or not, Chrome has a smooth scrolling flag that needs to be set to allow smooth scrolling. The choppiness has to do with the fact that JS is not async. Each step is performed one after another - so if you are running other JS functions while the scrolling takes place, it will hesitate until its the scrollings turn in the stack.

The Chrome flag does something that other browsers already do - Delay execution of other functions until the scrolling is complete. To enable smooth scrolling on Chrome, try:

1. Open a new tab and enter address chrome://flags/
2. Find Smooth Scrolling flag.
3. Click Enable
4. Restart Chrome browser...

Important Note: Most mobile devices delay JS execution while scrolling to preserve battery power. As such, if you are using JS driven smooth scroll on a mobile device, you will almost certainly notice hesitation.

Comment: It's working better now after i've activated the scrolling flag but still choppy :(
Is there a way to delay other functions my self when the scrolling animation is taking place?

Because on [this](http://mustafapiynirci.github.io/old-portfolio/) website it's working fine.

Comment: I dont want to lead you astray with an answer I am not sure about. The JS engine handles the stack internally. Chrome has always been a little choppy for me and the flag is the only solution I have found for that browser thus far. If someone has a better answer I would love to know myself. My solution is really only a semi-fix for people that are aware of the flag. Most of your users are likely going to not know about it and just leave the default settings.

Comment: Hmm yeah you are right about that. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: No problem, good luck finding a more universal answer! This is a very good question.